# Volume of the section surrounded by functions...

Tags: integration

Find the Volume of the section surrounded by functions

$z=2x^2+2y^2,\quad x^2+y^2=2x,\quad z=0$.

---

When converted these to $z=2x^2+2y^2, (x-1)^2+y^2=1, z=0$ 
,
I thought it may get easier if I convert Cartesian to cylindrical coordinates.

The results are $f_1: z=2r^2$ (?), $f_2: r=2\cos\theta$ and I tried this and failed.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\int_0^{2r^2}2r^2r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$
What makes me confused is whether setting $z=2\cos\theta$ is possible when $r=2\cos\theta$.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me, are you trying to evaluate the integral $$\iiint_{D}2x^2+2y^2dxdydz$$ where $D$ is the domain defined by $$D=\left\{(x,y,z)\;\;\text{s.t.}\;\; x^2+y^2=2x\;\;\text{and}\;\;z=0\right\}$$

Comment: yes. I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits  of $ \theta $ $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\int_0^{2r^2}2r^2r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

are questionable.

Also the function $2r^2$ in the integrand is not necessary because you just want to find the volume.

Otherwise your integral seems to be fine.

Comment: how can I get the volume under z=2x^2+2y^2 if not for 2r^2?

Comment: For the volume your function is $1$ and $2r^2$ appears in  the upper limit.

Comment: I gets 3pi. but you said limits of  θ are questionable. how so?